# Windows 7 network file copy slow when overwriting a lot of files

Tags: windows-7, networking

When copying multiple (>100) files from my Windows 7 x64 machine to a remote system the copy action becomes really slow when it needs to overwrite files. If I copy to an empty folder it is as fast as I would expect, but when copying to a folder and overwrting it becomes very slow. For example 300 files (about 4MB) takes then almost half an hour.

I already tried already the following:

- Disable Remote Differential Compression
- disabled the automatic adjustment for the TCP window size (netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled)
- Use TeraCopy

But it doesn't solve the problem. It is still very slow when overwriting files. The same action on a XP-machine takes only about 30 seconds to complete.

Comment: What are the specs of the target system?

Comment: HP Proliant server with Intel Xeon E5405 (2Ghz) processor. 4GB Ram. CPU usages around 5%, Memory usage around 1.5GB, Network usage around 5%.

Comment: it is Server 2003 R2

Comment: Try to add QoS packet scheduler into Network Adapter properties.